# WireMock unable to set log4j level to INFO instead of DEBUG

Tags: java, junit, log4j, jetty, wiremock

I'm running JUnit testcases with WireMock. Embedded Jetty Server is configured as follows.

```
@Before
public void setup() {


    final ResponseTemplateTransformer theTemplateTransformer =
            new ResponseTemplateTransformer(false);

    templateTransformerName = theTemplateTransformer.getName();

    mWireMockServer = new WireMockServer(
            WireMockConfiguration
                    .options()
                    .notifier(new ConsoleNotifier(false))
                    .extensions(theTemplateTransformer));
    mWireMockServer.start();


}
```

The output of the `setup()` method alone is very verbose, about 200 lines long. It starts like this:

```
> Task :processResources
> Task :classes
> Task :compileTestJava
> Task :processTestResources
> Task :testClasses
> Task :test
log4j: Threshold ="null".
log4j: Level value for root is  [DEBUG].
log4j: root level set to DEBUG
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender]
log4j: Setting property [immediateFlush] to [true].
log4j: Setting property [threshold] to [ALL].
log4j: Setting property [target] to [System.out].
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%5p] [%t] [%c{1}] [%F:%L] [%X{uuid}] - %m%n].
log4j: Adding appender named [ConsoleAppender] to category [root].
2019-12-09 11:28:06.813 [DEBUG] [Test worker] [log] [Log.java:159] [] - Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.util.log) via wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
2019-12-09 11:28:06.820 [ INFO] [Test worker] [log] [Log.java:169] [] - Logging initialized @1394ms to wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
2019-12-09 11:28:06.841 [DEBUG] [Test worker] [ContainerLifeCycle] [ContainerLifeCycle.java:412] [] - Server@2173e69b{STOPPED}[9.4.20.v20190813] added {QueuedThreadPool[qtp547179568]@209d4c30{STOPPED,8<=0<=14,i=0,r=-1,q=0}[NO_TRY],AUTO}
2019-12-09 11:28:06.856 [DEBUG] [Test worker] [ContainerLifeCycle] [ContainerLifeCycle.java:412] [] - HttpConnectionFactory@4f25c098[HTTP/1.1] added {HttpConfiguration@613f727b{32768/8192,8192/8192,https://:0,[]},POJO}
2019-12-09 11:28:06.864 [DEBUG] [Test worker] [ContainerLifeCycle] [ContainerLifeCycle.java:412] [] - NetworkTrafficServerConnector@5a238421{null,[]}{0.0.0.0:0} added {Server@2173e69b{STOPPED}[9.4.20.v20190813],UNMANAGED}
2019-12-09 11:28:06.865 [DEBUG] [Test worker] [ContainerLifeCycle] [ContainerLifeCycle.java:412] [] - NetworkTrafficServerConnector@5a238421{null,[]}{0.0.0.0:0} added {QueuedThreadPool[qtp547179568]@209d4c30{STOPPED,8<=0<=14,i=0,r=-1,q=0}[NO_TRY],AUTO}
2019-12-09 11:28:06.865 [DEBUG] [Test worker] [ContainerLifeCycle] [ContainerLifeCycle.java:412] [] - NetworkTrafficServerConnector@5a238421{null,[]}{0.0.0.0:0} added {ScheduledExecutorScheduler@5839ea4{STOPPED},AUTO}
2019-12-09 11:28:06.866 [DEBUG] [Test worker] [ContainerLifeCycle] [ContainerLifeCycle.java:412] [] - NetworkTrafficServerConnector@5a238421{null,[]}{0.0.0.0:0} added {wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.io.ArrayByteBufferPool@f73022f,POJO}
```

**I do not want to print out DEBUG logs, just INFO level stuff**. I tried to do this by changing the WireMock Configuration as follows. What I'm doing is described in the [official documentation](http://wiremock.org/docs/configuration/), section *Notification (logging)*, so feel free to have a look.

```
.notifier(new ConsoleNotifier(false)) //attribute verbose is set to false
```

Also tried to solve this by adding a log4j.properties file under src/test/resources/

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.logger.org.apache.http.wire=INFO
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 7):

This worked in my case (Spring, Logback) - src/test/resources/logback-test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />

    <!-- Decrease amount of logs from Jetty started by WireMock -->
    <logger name="org.eclipse.jetty" level="info"/>
    <logger name="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler" level="warn"/>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you ... I'm really enjoying the sudden silence!

Comment: Work's like magic.